# How to "truncate" a text inside textview in android according to the orientation?

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.1

I created a simple java function to truncate a string to be displayed in my list view. I am displaying a news title and below this a news summary. I would like to have the same behavior as the image below. Currently, i am truncating the news title with 45 chars and then appending "..." at the end of it. However, when I change the orientation to landscape, the title could appear without being truncated. I dont think the app below truncates the news title, but it keeps the title in a single line and automatically "truncates".

[image]

How can I achieve this behavior in my app?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you need to truncate title manually. Android TextView component has [ellipsize](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:ellipsize) attribute that will do that for you. That also should adopt to any screen orientation.